# Trying to display a date in Spanish

Tags: php, datetime, localization

Nothing is working for me. Here is the code snippet I tried

```
$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
echo strftime("%a %d %b %Y", $row['eventtime']); 
setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);
```

I have also tried this

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
$originalDate = "04/01/2014";
$originalDate =date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
$newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this code

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish'); 
$date = $date = str_replace("/","-","04/01/2014");
echo strftime('%d %B %Y',strtotime($date));
```

So now it's showing `04 enero 2014` but is there a way I can make `enero` into `ene` like short hand?

Both the code are showing date in English only. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really ought to set your locale in php.ini, not dynamically.

And, it_IT is an Italian locale not a Spanish one.

You want the `strftime()` method in the first code snippet.

Finally, locale names are different on different operating systems.

Try:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
```

Comment: @badZeni i updated my question with another snippet it worked for me by little bit twisting the code

Comment: From the php documentation:

%b  Abbreviated month name, based on the locale  Jan through Dec

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 0):

By changing the %B to %b you will have the following output:

04 ene 2014

More info about strftime [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).